How to remove hex codes that are visible during transition while using gganimate library in R?
I created an animated bar plot using ggplot and gganimate. The data labels are numbers and are comma separated using the comma function in the scales library. But while the bars are changing from one year to another year the data labels are also changing and during the transition hex codes are visible instead of numbers. How to resolve this issue?
The code is as follows:
staticplot <- ggplot(data, aes(rank, group = variable_name, 
                               fill = as.factor(variable_name), color = as.factor(variable_name))) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = value / 2,
                height = value,
                width = 0.9), alpha = 0.8, color = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = paste(variable_name, " "), hjust = 1), 
            vjust = 0.2, size = 6) +
  geom_text(aes(y = value / 2, label = Value_lbl , hjust = -1), 
            color = "black", size = 8) + 
  coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 30, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", colour = "black", vjust = 0),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 18, hjust = 0.5, face = "italic", color = "black"),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 8, hjust = 0.5, face = "italic", color = "black"),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 4, "cm"))

anim <- staticplot + transition_states(year, transition_length = 20, state_length = 30, wrap = TRUE) +
  view_follow(fixed_x = FALSE, fixed_y = TRUE)  +
  labs(title = 'Yearly Comparison : {closest_state}')

A snippet of the data is as follows:

A snippet of the gif is as follows which shows the hexcodes:


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including your code and a snippet of your input data if required best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

I have added the code and the data snippet. Kindly check.

Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

this is fairly easy to reproduce:
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
df <- data.frame(
year = 2001:2005,
value = 1:5*1000
)
p <- ggplot(df) +
geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = value, label = scales::label_comma()(value)))
p +
transition_states(
year,
transition_length = 20,
state_length = 30,
wrap = TRUE)

Related? I suspect this is because gganimate has no idea how to interpolate strings. If you need the commas, you may need to pre-calculate the intermediate steps yourself.
